# Rails eager load using includes and nested belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Say i have three models:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :other_thing
end

class OtherThing
  has_many :things
end
```

How can i go from `Foo` and eager load `OtherThing` along the lines of:

`Foo.includes([:things => [:other_things]})`

I've searched but can't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `Foo.includes(:things => :other_thing)`? (singular on other_thing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

includes and joins use the same syntax as your defined your relations:

```
Foo.includes(:things => :other_thing)
```

Will work because:

```
Foo has_many :things
                   ^
Thing belongs_to :other_thing
                            ^^
```

But keep in mind that in the where clause, always use the pluralized version:

```
Foo.includes(:things => :other_thing).where(other_things: { name: 'Bobby' })
                                   ^^                 ^^
```